# Simplification of product of covariances for gaussians

Tags: normal-distribution, covariance

$X = Y + Z$ Where $Y$ and $Z$ are independent Gaussians with zero means and known variances.

How do you simplify the left side of this to equal the right side?

[image]

I think I see why $Cov(Y+Z,Y+Z)$ equals $\sigma_{Y}^2+\sigma_{Z}^2$, but don't know why its in the denominator or how the numerator is obtained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a mistake somewhere in the book or wherever you got the problem. It should be:

$$\frac{\text{Cov}(Y,Y+Z)}{\text{Cov}(Y+Z,Y+Z)}x=\ldots$$
since:
$$\require{cancel}\text{Cov}(Y,Y+Z)=\text{Cov}(Y,Y)+\cancel{\text{Cov}(Y,Z)}=\sigma_Y^2$$
and the denominator is as you said:
$$\text{Cov}(Y+Z,Y+Z)=\text{Cov}(Y,Y)+\cancel{\text{Cov}(Y,Z)}+\cancel{\text{Cov}(Z,Y)}+\text{Cov}(Z,Z)=\sigma_Y^2+\sigma_Z^2$$

Comment: Thanks this must have been an error in the solution. Does the fact that Y and Z are independent imply that $Cov(Y,Z)$ is zero?

Comment: Yes, independent implies uncorrelated (if the second moment exists).

Comment: Ah ok I always mix that up

Comment: hey sorry I thought I understood why $\text{Cov}(Y,Y+Z)=\text{Cov}(Y,Y)+\text{Cov}(Y,Z)$, but now I can't remember. Would you mind breaking this part down too when you get a chance?